# Regarding FTL's SimpleScalar

Tags: java, freemarker

## Background

In my `ftl` file I had the following `<#if>` statement

```
<#if payout.paymentType.name == "StoreCredit">
```

Well, it turns out that statement generates the following error

```
Caused by: The only legal comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, or two dates.
Left  hand operand is a freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
Right hand operand is a freemarker.template.SimpleScalar
```

It took me awhile to find out that it was *this* `<#if>` causing the problem, and **I fixed it like this**.

```
<#if payout.paymentType.name() == "StoreCredit">
```

I was under the impression, for some reason, that a `SimpleScalar` was a type of number.  After googling for awhile, I found out that wasn't the case.

## Question

Why is `"StoreCredit"` considered a `freemarker.template.SimpleScalar`?

Is that just the way FTL represents strings?

Is `SimpleScalar` ever used to represent something other than strings? or is this just a genericized token meant for other uses as well.

Comment: Why did it take a while to figure out *which* `#if` causes the problem? The error message always contains the line and column numbers, and the quotation of the failing expression. If it doesn't, something removes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's for representing a Java `String`, and that only.

As the API documentation (JavaDoc) says, `SimpleScalar` is "A simple implementation of the `TemplateScalarModel` interface", and `TemplateScalarModel` is the " ''string'' template language data-type; like in Java, an unmodifiable UNICODE character sequence. (The name of this interface should be `TemplateStringModel`. The misnomer is inherited from the old times, when this was the only single-value type in FreeMarker.)". Numbers are represented by the implementations of `TemplateNumberModel`.

BTW, FreeMarker 2.3.20 has less cryptic type-error messages. It talks about strings, numbers, booleans, etc. `SimpleScalar` and such are technical details that causal FreeMarker users shouldn't worry about.

Answer (score 2):

```
<if payout.paymentType.name??>
    <#if payout.paymentType.name?string == "StoreCredit">
    </#if>
</#if>
```

Comment: This answer seems to be unrelated... It will also fail, as `name` is not a JavaBean property (as there's no `getName()`) but a method. And if it wasn't, the `?string` part is redundant.